# How to make a Kubernetes "LoadBalancer" service point to an Ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes

I've been using Kubernete's `LoadBalancer` type service for incoming traffic on AWS. However, it is hard to terminate SSL at a service level, thus the idea of using an Ingress.

However, a `LoadBalancer` service allows us to make as many rolling changes as we like to our deployments without having to configure our DNS. By using Ingress, you can only use `NodePort` and while we would like to use Ingress, mapping DNS to new node when the pod is deployed on another node is a problem.

Is there a way to point a Kubernetes to point to an Ingress controller or use a service type `LoadBalancer` with an Ingress controller to terminate SSL.

We do not want to put our SSL certificates in a container, which is why this trouble.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to point a Kubernetes to point to an Ingress controller or use a service type LoadBalancer with an Ingress controller to terminate SSL.

You can simply deploy the on metal (nginx, haproxy, traefic...) ingress controllers as a pod/daemonset/rc in your cluster, and front it with a service of type=loadbalancer. You can find these controllers in various places like: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx, https://libraries.io/go/github.com%2Ftimelinelabs%2Fromulus, https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/fa25c8ef221d89719bd0c491b66bbf54e3d40438/docs/toml.md#kubernetes-ingress-backend,